# Conduit/wires to panel box

Tags: wiring

Is it always two copper wires (one circuit) that you can run through when connecting a conduit to the box? The reason why I am asking was wondering if it is permissible to run four wires (two different circuits) to the panel box? Running out of connections to panel. Trying not to have a sub panel box yet. I do have one more slot that I can use if need be if you can't run the four wires or two different circuits which would be okay too.

Comment: How fat are the wires and how big is the conduit?

Comment: What kind of conduit is this, metal or plastic? Are the wires loose, that is, not in a sheath? Is there a ground wire or is the conduit the ground?

Comment: And what country are you located?

Comment: E.M.T. 1/2 inch conduit with one of the circuits wit 14 gauge wires (white//black) and the other is 12 gauge copper wires. (white/black) in Illinois (cook county)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes you can run 2 circuits in 1 conduit. There are some limitations depending on the size and type of wire or cable and the conduit size. If you provide the needed ampacity of each circuit and conduit size / current wire type we can provide you with what would be allowed by code in the areas we know (providing your country / state) we may be able to get quite specific.

Added:

See the comment below but you have way more room to add circuits with the wire you mentioned. You should be using wire listed as THWN most of the wire I purchase today is listed as THHN /THWN.  THWN or wire listed for a wet location  is required when the conduit is outside or a wet location. Illinois is on the 2008 NEC. The wire size, fill and type have not changed for years. Note source for NEC In ILLINOIS is the NEC In effect 1-1-2017.
Good luck and be safe.
2nd note I was lazy and used table values for #12 since there were 2 sizes. 1/2" THHN / THWN the max conductors for #12 is 9. The max fill if they were all #14 is 12 , with 12 conductors the derate would be 50% so as long as you stay below 9 conductors your wire size and ampacity is not affected.

Comment: E.m.t 1/2 inch conduit to panel box with one circuit 12 gauge copper (black/white) and the other 14 gauge (black/white) copper wires to the panel box. A total of 4 wires in Illinois cook county

Comment: 1/2 EMT can have a max fill of 9 conductors THHN/THWN. The derating schedule 4-6 current caring conductors is 80%. The maximum current that THHN/THWN handle for derating is 30 amps but the max breaker for #12 is 20 amps so there is no problem with your current fill. You can go up to 9 current carying derated at 70% the max fill for 1/2" . The 14 gauge has a similar derating for THHN/THWN 25 amp max for derating purposes but limited to 15 amp max circuit breaker. So you have almost enough room to double your branch circuits if needed. These values are straight from the code book tables.

Comment: Thank u! When I look At sparky,  YouTube and stacks--when I see a panel box in installed with 1/2 inch conduit, I always see maybe 20 slots to 30 slots with only 2 wires through. But in reality I could use an existing conduit to run additional wires to the box without creating new EMT with another new circuit.  I do of course agree with NEC codes but never saw it to the panel box. Then why aren't more people doing thais? Oh well. Thank you again for your great help. Didn't mean to confuse you, just curious.  I do understand it is easier to trace each slot.

Answer (score 1):

Conduit fill has 2 rules:

### Physical space in conduit

If you [google "conduit fill table"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=conduit%20fill%20table&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), you'll find tables showing how many wires are allowed to *physically* fit.   This has to do with damage to wires, particularly when it's tight and you're pulling that last wire.  ThreePhaseEel and Ed Beal address this.

### Thermal limits in conduit

*This is the one everyone ignores*.  **It'll get you in *big* trouble!**

TLDR: In 12-14 AWG wire, 4 circuits of any kind in any size of conduit.   This assumes you have North American split-phase service or no more than 2 phases of 3-phase.

---

The gory details:  The issue is thermal.  Many wires in a conduit running at near max, will make so much heat in a confined space that the wires will melt.  So if too many wires are in a conduit of any size, you must "de-rate", or reduce the current in the wires to keep them cool and in their efficient range.

The NEC has tables in 310.16 that list the hard absolute maximum currents allowed for a wire.  NEC Table 310.15b2a says if you have 4-6 *current-carrying conductors* in conduit, derate down to 80%, and if 7-9, go to 70%.  If 10-20, go to 50% (ouch).

The table lists 30A for 12 AWG wire, and a 70% derate puts that at 21 amps.  As you know, another rule limits 12 AWG to 20 amps max.  So we don't need to care about a 70% derate (7-9 conductors).  Similar math works for 14 AWG.  (if you're working 10 AWG or up, then you gotta get out the sharp pencil).

So what's a *current-carrying conductor*?  And why multiples of 3?   A conductor is a wire that normally carries meaningful current, i.e. makes heat.  *i.e. not grounds.*  Let's briefly talk about split-phase (hot-neutral-hot):  Neutral only carries differential current, e.g. 19/1/20A.  Wire heating is proportional to current *squared*.  So 20-10-10 is better than 20-20-0 or 20-0-20.  Worst case, split-phase counts as 2 wires.  (That also applies to 3-phase with neutral, which is why multiples of 3).  So...

- A simple hot-neutral circuit counts as 2 conductors: 20A on the hot and 20A on the neutral.
- A 240V hot-hot circuit counts as 2 conductors: 20A on L1 and 20A on L2.
- A 120/240 hot-neutral-hot counts as 2 conductors, as discussed.
- A MWBC counts as 2 conductors, same reason.
- A subpanel feed counts as 2 conductors, same reason.

Any circuit you can have in a 120/240 split-phase panel counts as 2 conductors. *Period*.

That means a maximum of 4 circuits per conduit.

Don't run a big fat conduit from your panel to the middle of your house and stuff it with 20 circuits!  Instead use multiple smaller conduits - 3/4" pipe will suffice - at the correct spacing so they can cool.

Comment: If possible running a big fat 2/0 to a 125A subpanel to other side of house would be better than a lot small circuits.

Answer (score 0):

### You have *plenty* of space

Your two 12AWG and two 14 AWG THHNs take up ~30mm^2 of fill.  Using the 40% rule (i.e. more than two conductors in the conduit) column in the conduit fill tables for EMT, this gets you 70mm^2 of space in a ½" EMT.  This means that you can add two more completely independent branch circuits (or a MWBC) with 12AWG, or even 3 independent branch circuits (or two MWBCs) with 14AWG, and still not be out of space.